# How to solve a "1st arg can't be coerced to String" for a jaydebeapi.connect command?

Tags: java, python, jython, windows-server-2016, jaydebeapi

On Windows Server 2016, we are trying to connect over JDBC with a Jython script but our `jaydebeapi.connect` statement is giving the following error:

> TypeError: getConnection(): 1st arg can't be coerced to String

Yet, when we look at [examples of using jaydebeapi](https://pypi.org/project/JayDeBeApi/), the first argument *is* a string.

This is our Python code:

```
jclassname = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" 
database = "our_database_name"
db_elem = ";databaseName={}".format(database) if database else ""
host = "###.##.###.###" # ip address
port = "1433"    
user = "user_name"
password = "password"  
url = (jdbc:sqlserver://{host}:{port}{db_elem}"        ";user={user};password={password}".format(host=host, port=port, db_elem=db_elem,  er=user, password=password)    )    
print url
driver_args = [url]
jars = None
libs = None
db = jaydebeapi.connect(jclassname, driver_args, jars=jars, libs=libs)
```

This is how we are running our Python script:

```
C:\jython2.7.0\bin\jython.exe C:\path_to_our_script.py
```

**What are we missing? How do we solve this string coercion error for our jaydebeapi.connect statement?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*From `JayDeBeApi` Docs* -

> Basically you just import the `jaydebeapi` Python module and execute the
>   `connect` method. This gives you a DB-API conform connection to the
>   database.
>
> The first argument to `connect` is the name of the Java driver class.
>   The second argument is a string with the JDBC connection URL. Third
>   you can optionally supply a sequence consisting of user and password
>   or alternatively a dictionary containing arguments that are internally
>   passed as properties to the Java `DriverManager.getConnection` method.
>   See the Javadoc of [DriverManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html) class for details.

You are getting this error from the `DriverManager.getConnection` method.

From the JavaDocs for `DriverManager` -

```
public static Connection getConnection(String url, Properties info)
```

So, your `jaydebeapi.connect` function call is messed up. Your second argument should be the `url` as a string.

Following is a sample snippet from the `JayDeBeApi` docs.

> ```
> >>> import jaydebeapi
> >>> conn = jaydebeapi.connect("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver",
> ...                           "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:.",
> ...                           ["SA", ""],
> ...                           "/path/to/hsqldb.jar",)
> ```

Comment: Yes, the URL did need to be a string. We thought it was but we realized it was this line that was wrong: "driver_args = [url]"  That line turned the string into a list. Once we removed that, the code worked.